Setting up a client to ping local host over TCP/HTTP with FastAPI + Uvicorn server in same application
I have setup a server to server basic Get, Inference (type of Get), Post request using FastAPI and Uvicorn.
@app.post("/post")
def post(payload: dict):
    return payload


async def main():
    logger.info("Running")
    config = uvicorn.Config(
        "sagemaker.app:app",
        host="127.0.0.1",
        port=9007,
        log_level="info",
        loop="asyncio",
        reload=True,
        workers=3,
        use_colors=True,
    )
    server = uvicorn.Server(config)
    logger.info("I'm just waiting for a connection")
    await server.serve()

I have a usecase of hitting the Get and Inference path from within the application itself. However I am getting ConnectionRefused errors when i try to ping local host
Things I've tried

Simple URLLib to hit 127.0.0.1, 9007. Does not work. I see a connection refused error.
Socket - this works partially , but i keep getting address bind errors. I can't kill the server as it needs to be long living.

        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        client.bind((target_host, target_port))
 
        # connect the client
        client.connect((target_host, target_port))
 
        # send some data
        request = "GET /generate HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1:9007\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.31.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 33\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n"
        client.send(request.encode())
 
        # receive some data
        response = client.recv(4096)
        logger.info(response.decode("UTF-8"))
        client.close()


I am able to query local host from different tabs in a Jupyter notebook.


import requests
 
result = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:9007/', verify=False).json()
 
print (result)


requests.Session()

DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1:9007
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://127.0.0.1:9007 "GET / HTTP/11" 200 17
send: b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1:9007\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.32.3\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: date: Tue, 06 Aug 2024 01:44:44 GMT
header: server: uvicorn
header: content-length: 17
header: content-type: application/json
{'Hello': 'World'}
<requests.sessions.Session at 0x7fd462a9bbe0>

Is there any suggestion of setting up a client in the same server application which can be used to hit local host?

This question is similar to: Cannot connect to fast api server at localhost:8000 from my application which is running under a docker container. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
